# Redux-saga dispatch return so many requests

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, axios, redux-saga

i am build my services with Axios my reducers and actions is build based on Duck pattern but all is working but my `dispatch()` in `componentDidMount()` it's send so many request to my API.

[image: This send almost 3k of calls in 3 minutes!]

I've already tried with yield cancel() saga middleware with take() but but nothing works :/

**ducks/table.js**

```
export const Types = {
  GET_ALL: 'booking/GET_ALL'
};

const initialState = {
  all: null
};

export default function reducer(state = initialState, action) {
  const { type, payload } = action;

  switch (type) {
    case Types.GET_ALL:
      return { 
        ...state,
        all: payload
      };
    default:
      return state;
  }

}

export const fetchAll = data => ({ type: Types.GET_ALL, payload: data });
```

**services/table.js**

```
import Http from "../utils/http";

export const getAll = async () => {
  try {
    const response = await Http.get('/todos/1');

    if (response.data) {
      return response.data;
    }

    throw response.data;
  } catch (error) {
    throw error;
  }
};
```

**sagas/table.js**

```
import { put, call } from 'redux-saga/effects';

import { getAll } from '../services/table'
import { fetchAll } from '../ducks/table';

export function* tableCheck(action) {
    try {       

        let data = yield call(getAll);
        yield put(fetchAll(data));

        console.log("tableCheck => try => action", action)      

    } catch (error) {

        //ToDo criar authError
        yield put(error)
    }
}
```

**store/index.js**

```
import { createStore, applyMiddleware } from "redux";
import createSagaMiddleware from "redux-saga";

import reducers from "./reducers";
import rootSaga from "./sagas";

const sagaMiddleware = createSagaMiddleware();

const store = createStore(reducers, applyMiddleware(sagaMiddleware));

sagaMiddleware.run(rootSaga);

export default store;
```

**store/sagas.js**

```
import { takeLatest } from 'redux-saga/effects';

import { tableCheck } from '../sagas/table';

import { Types as bookingTypes } from '../ducks/table';

export default function* rootSaga() {
    yield takeLatest(bookingTypes.GET_ALL, tableCheck)
}
```

**store/reducer.js**

```
import { combineReducers } from "redux";

import bookings from "../ducks/table";

const appReducer = combineReducers({
  bookings
});
const rootReducer = (state, action) => {
  return appReducer(state, action);
};

export default rootReducer;
```

**components/app.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';

import Table from "./common/table";
import { fetchAll } from './ducks/table';

class App extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      headers: ["#", "Name", "Check In", "Date", "Status"]
    };

    this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);    
  }

  async componentDidMount() {    
    //console.log("app => componentDidMount() => fetchAll()", await fetchAll())
    console.log("app => componentDidMount() => this.state", await this.state);
    console.log("app => componentDidMount() => this.props", await this.props);
    await this.props.dispatch(fetchAll());

    //<Table headings={this.state.headers} />

  }



  handleClick(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log("class App => handleClick() => this.props", this.props);
    console.log("class App => handleClick() => this.state", this.state);

  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <p className="header">React Table Component</p>

        <p>
          Made with ❤️ by <b>Gabriel Correa</b>
        </p>
        <button onClick={this.handleClick}>Testar</button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => ({ payload: state });

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(App);
```

Thanks for help xD

Comment: Try to replace call with takeLatest?

Comment: @AndonMitev in my `store/sagas.js`?

Comment: Yes, i'm not 100%sure tho

Comment: @AndonMitev I am already call with `yield takeLatest(bookingTypes.GET_ALL, tableCheck)` :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
yield put(fetchAll(data));
```

You're dispatching `fetchAll` in the saga `tableCheck`. It will trigger the `takeLatest` in your root saga in an infinite loop:

```
yield takeLatest(bookingTypes.GET_ALL, tableCheck)
```

This is likely why you're seeing so many requests.

---

#### Solution

As described in the comments:

> The way I would approach this instead is split up fetchAll to at least fetchAllRequest and fetchAllSuccess (GET_ALL_REQUEST and GET_ALL_SUCCESS). app.js and takeLatest use fetchAllRequest/GET_ALL_REQUEST instead. put and the reducer use fetchAllSuccess/GET_ALL_SUCCESS instead.

Comment: How to refactor? using  `cancel()` in my `yield put(fetchAll(data));`?

Comment: I am try to remove `yield put(fetchAll(data))` and use only `return yield call(getAll)` but not work :(

Comment: I was just merely explaining why Redux-saga dispatch return so many requests. The way I would approach this instead is split up `fetchAll` to at least `fetchAllRequest` and `fetchAllSuccess` (`GET_ALL_REQUEST` and `GET_ALL_SUCCESS`). `app.js` and `takeLatest` use `fetchAllRequest`/`GET_ALL_REQUEST` instead. `put` and the reducer use `fetchAllSuccess`/`GET_ALL_SUCCESS` instead.